# Using orderby in php put make it descending....how?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make it so that users can sort a certain column ascending or descending by clicking on little arrow .gif links.

Here's some code:

```
echo("<tr><td><a href=\"?orderby=quarterback_first desc\"><!-- IMAGE HERE --></a>First Name</td>");
```

My issue is that ?=orderby=quarterback_first works just fine, but as soon as I put the desc in there it doesn't know that I want it to sort it descending. Is there a command or something I'm missing to make it so that it will sort it the way I want? Thanks for your time! First post, be nice. :)

Thanks for responses. Here's more code:

```
$orders=array("quarterback_draft_pick", "quarterback_pass_rating", "quarterback_first","quarterback_last", "quarterback_draft_year","quarterback_draft_round","quarterback_pass_comps","quarterback_pass_yards","quarterback_pass_td","quarterback_pass_int");
$key=array_search($_GET['orderby'],$orders);
$orderby=$orders[$key];
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're putting this straight in a MySQL query. What does the query look like after you put the part with `desc` in?

Comment: Did you write or inherit this code? What you've posted is filtering the `orderby` param against a set of allowed values. Adding the " desc" causes the validation to fail. Separate the `orderby` and direction parameters as Frits explains below

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more sensible solution would be:

```
?orderby=quarterback_first&direction=desc
```

Just add a second parameter.

Comment: I find something like this works well for validating the direction parameter - `$direction = isset($_GET['direction']) && strtoupper($_GET['direction']) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';`

Answer (score 0):

watch the space between 'quarterback_first' and 'desc'

try:

```
echo("<tr><td><a href=\"?orderby=quarterback_first&sort=desc\"><!-- IMAGE HERE --></a>First Name</td>");
```

and grap the desc-value via $_GET['sort']

Comment: I'm a bit confused how I should grap the desc value while including it inside a variable that SQL would understand.

Comment: SQL-Satatement: ... Select * From x ORDER BY column DESC ... in your case use e.g. Select * From x ORDER BY $orderby strtoupper($_GET['sort'])